# bcc32c Error integer literal is too large to be represented in any integer type

Tags: c++, c++builder, clang++, literals

I have a large __int64 literal:

```
const __int64 PwTab[] = {
                        50036500600837093008i64,
                        3006206760097890820056i64
                        };
```

It is accepted nicely by `bcc32` (Borland classic compiler) but not by `bcc32c` (clang).

The error for the clang compiler is:

> integer literal is too large to be represented in any integer type

I use the `i64` suffix to tell the computer it is a 64bit integer literal.

How can I write an `__int64` literal in clang, which is also compatible with the `__int64` type in the classic compiler?

Comment: Don't use `__int64` nor `i64` prefix. Those are deprecated Microsoft specific feature. Use instead `long long` (or better `ìnt64_t`) type and `ll` suffix.

Comment: Also, `50'036'500'600'837'093'008` requires at least 66 bits to represent (67 if signed). What value do you expect the 64 bit integer to hold?

Comment: @Brian You are correct, I didn't notice that, yet it compiles in bcc32... there is likely some truncating or overflow happening without being reported by the compiler... I'll have to examine this in more details... thank you for your comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments the problem was in `bcc32` not reporting too large literal during the compile time but silently overflowing which of course created completely different array than expected during runtime.

e.g.

```
int64_t testVar = 0x112233445566778899aai64;
```

Which is of course larger than what 64-bit integer can accept and results in runtime value of:

```
0x33445566778899aa
```

A sidenote - `ll` suffix doesn't work in Borland classic compiler. So I have to use `i64` in it. But it won't be a problem after switching to `clang`.